# Error: code length overflow. (24956>23648)?

Tags: reactjs, qr-code

Im using Reactjs react-qr-code for showing a data in qr code. The qr code accept only a particular length of data , otherwise it will show above error. I there anyway to increase this length

```
Error: code length overflow. (24956>23648)
```

Comment: according to this answer https://github.com/zpao/qrcode.react/issues/69 it's not possible

Comment: No, this is not possible. Why do you need to show that much data in a QR code? QR codes are not meant for publishing books.

Comment: https://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html - QR code sizes and *maximum* data that can be represented. Note the maximum data is a function of the size *and* ECC level.. and is finite in all cases. Compression/encoding or shortening proxies may be useful to solve different problems.

Comment: @KenWhite One might ask why more than 1000 (or whatever limits old browsers had) characters should be allowed in URLs.. should check out some of the Splunk queries I share at work..